# Query works fine on mysql but gives out error in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
         SET @today=CAST(NOW() AS CHAR(64)) , 
         @yesterday=CAST(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE) ;
         select sum(quantity)
         from orders o,product p,order2product op
          where o.order_id = op.order_id AND op.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date < @today AND order_date > @yesterday
```

It gives out the following

```
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum(quantity)from orders o,product p,order2product op where o.order_id = ' at line 1
```

But works fine when I use it in mysql directly. Whats the issue?

UPDATE

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SET @today=CAST(NOW() AS CHAR(64)),@yesterday=CAST(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL - 1 DAY) AS DATE); select sum(quantity)from orders o,product p,order2product op where o.order_id = op.order_id AND op.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date < @today AND order_date > @yesterday") or die(mysql_error());

$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums.
if($existCount > 0)
{
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
    $dayQuantity = $row["sum(quantity)"];   
 }
}
```

Comment: please, post your php code

Comment: please see the updated section

Comment: You have two queries in that string, not one. `mysql_*()` (which is deprecated and shouldn't be used) doesn't support that. You'll need to send two queries separately, or update to `mysqli_*()` which supports `multi_query()`, or both.

Comment: I tried $sql = $mysqli->query("SET @today=CAST(NOW() AS CHAR(64)),@yesterday=CAST(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL - 1 DAY) AS DATE);select sum(quantity)from orders o,product p,order2product op where o.order_id = op.order_id AND op.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date < @today AND order_date > @yesterday"); but it doesn't work, I'm aving trouble understanding it's syntax

Comment: While you should definitely switch away from mysql_*(), you could try submitting your SQL with the variables. Just move that junk into the `SELECT` statement like `Select sum(quantity)from orders o,product p,order2product op where o.order_id = op.order_id AND op.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL - 1 DAY) AND NOW();`